# Elixir ExAdmin, how to define boolean input as a checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, elixir, exadmin

In ExAdmin, how can I make the input field of a boolean render as a checkbox.
By default (i.e. empty `register_resource App.Reservation do end`) it shows up as a checkbox, but I need to customize the form and can't get it to be a checkbox when defining it in the inputs list.

```
register_resource App.Reservation do
  form reservation do
    inputs do
      input reservation, :is_booked
    end 
  end
end
```

The documentation mentions `check_boxes` and `radio` for groups but not for single fields.

`input reservation, :is_booked` will create a text field.

`input reservation, :is_booked, type: :boolean` will create a text field that says `true` as a default value.

Would like to have it as a checkbox

Comment: How about `input reservation, :is_booked, type: :checkbox`? (I've never used ex_admin.)

Comment: That results in a big text field that remains active after clicking it but doesn't register keystrokes. I've tried a bunch of different types, check_boxes is what is used for groups, radio doesn't work neither. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Why don't try to "fix" that text field which says ´true´ on template side? (just wondering based on little phoenix and rails) -> https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#summary

Comment: I will probably end up doing that but it should be possible to do it with the build in functions, I just don't know how yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that I forgotten to define the field type in model. Once I did that it worked!

```
schema "users" do
  ...
  field :active, :boolean, default: false
  ...
end
```

in admin for user.ex

```
inputs do
...
  input user, :active
...
end
```

Comment: What did you write in your ExAdmin file? The field is already defined as a boolean in my app

Comment: Updated answer.